# C# Form Instant Call

Tags: c#, forms, paint, repaint, instant

I'm working on a project where a function must be called as fast as it can be. But, I still have to manage throughout the `Form` lifecycle. I've tried with Timers but I need something without delay.

I've tried to override the `WndProc`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
   base.WndProc(ref m);
   if (AllowDraw) G.DrawFrame();
}
```

But this only works when the `Windows OS` sends a message to the `Form`, so it doesn't work. I need something I can override, or a simple trick, to make my method be called in every cycle of the `Form` lifecycle (if it has any).

Comment: while(true){...}? Is this specific to a paint action and that is why this is difficult?

Comment: while(true){...} hangs the form code lifecycle...
Now it must not hangs it, so i need something that runs every time when the form's code do a cycle...

Comment: I assumed you meant on a different thread of course. Like I said, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: No, it must be in the same thread... AND it must be called by the form...
I would use while(true) if i can... But the retarded GarbageCollector would never release the unused objects and i will run out of memory...